# JSF how to convert simple number to time?

Tags: jsf

I want to convert a number based on 24-hour clock to 12-hour clock for display. I only have a simple number such as 1, 2, or 23, not a date object.

For example: 1 to 1am, 2 to 2am, ..., 22 to 10pm 23 to 11pm,

How do I it in JSF?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`<f:convertDateTime>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/convertDateTime.html) for this. This not only supports `java.util.Date`, but this also supports the time in millis (as obtained by `Date#getTime()`). Multiply your hour with 360000 to get the hour in milliseconds and then use `<f:convertDatetime>` with a pattern of `ha` to get the hour in AM-PM (`h`) along with the AM-PM marker (`a`).

```html
<h:outputText value="#{bean.hour * 360000}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="ha" />
</h:outputText>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want? a Date object or just the output text from an integer?

Create a Date Object and use a Calendar to set its value and then set its hour format to 12 hours.

Or calculate 24 modulo 12 and add "am" or "pm" regarding if value was bigger then 12 or not.